# Picklist translated values not displaying for community guest user

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, translation-workbench

I have a picklist visible to site guest user via a public page.  I translated few values into Arabic using translation workbench. The translated values display OK for authenticated users but not for site guest user. For site guest user, I changed the language (from community language picker) to Arabic but I receive English values for the picklist only. Apart from the picklist, the static labels correctly display the Arabic translation. Page displays RTL. Only picklist doesn't display translated values.

Following Apex code is being called from LWC component.

```
Map<String,String> categoryMap = new Map<String,String>();
    try {
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = 
        Directory__c.Category__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry pe: picklistValues) {
            categoryMap.put(pe.getLabel(),pe.getValue());
            System.debug('*** = '+pe.getValue() + '*** = '+pe.getLabel() + ' **** ' + UserInfo.getLanguage());
        }
        return categoryMap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The debug logs shows user Language as 'ar' (Arabic) but labels are returned in English.
anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you sure Arabic is enabled for community?

Comment: Does https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219290/retrieving-picklist-translations-in-lightning-component-in-communities help?

Comment: Yes, Arabic is added to the community languages

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved. I picked  Arabic(UAE) instead of 'Arabic' as language in the community. Removing Arabic(UAE) and adding Arabic solved the issue